# Work done in compression of a spherical bubble inside water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work, gas

Please note that I am not asking for a direct solution to my question or asking someone to check my steps/method (which is the reason given for closing it). **In the following question, we are asked to find out the work done during adiabatic compression of a bubble. Since the bubble has gas inside, I feel the formula for work done during adiabatic process on a gas is applicable. However, the correct answer is obtained by calculating work done as that in bulk compression (using stress-strain). Why is the adiabatic work not giving the correct result? In which situations is it not applicable?**

#### Question

> A spherical bubble inside water has radius $R$. The pressure inside the bubble is equal to the water pressure with value $p_\circ$. The bubble is now radially compressed in an adiabatic manner so that its radius becomes $R-a$, with $a<<R$. The value of $\gamma = C_p/C_v = 41/30$. The magnitude of work done in the process is given by $n(4\pi Ra^2p_\circ)$. Then find the value of $n$.

#### Answer

> $2.05$ $(= 3\gamma/2)$

**My approach**
Work done in an adiabatic process in going from state $(P_1,V_1)$ to $(P_2,V_2)$ is given by
$$ W = \frac{P_2V_2-P_1V_1}{\gamma -1}$$

Here, volume change and hence pressure change are small so that using $PV^\gamma$ = constant in an adiabatic process we get
$$W = \frac{P\mathrm{d}V+V\mathrm{d}P}{\gamma -1}$$
where $\mathrm{d}V = 4\pi R^2a$ and
$\mathrm{d}P/P = -\gamma \mathrm{d}V/V$

This method gives the magnitude of work done as $W = P\mathrm{d}V = 4p_\circ\pi R^2a$ which certainly does not fit the expression of the question, let alone yield the correct answer.

After thinking about it for some more time, I got the answer with this method
$$W = \frac{1}{2} \text{stress}\times\text{strain}\times\text{volume}$$

The stress being the pressure difference that caused the compression, i.e. $\mathrm{d}P$ found in my previous approach, the strain being $\mathrm{d}V/V$ and volume $V = 4/3\pi R^3$. Doing the simplification gives the correct expression and the correct value of $n$.

However, I have never seen this formula being used for compression of gases, so I am extremely doubtful if this is the correct approach or if there's another approach to give the correct answer. Also, I would appreciate an insight into why my first method was wrong as well.

Comment: Please let me know what to edit in this question so that it is reopened again. I was clear in what my main question is - **that *why* was the bulk compression formula used here to find the work done instead of the usual formula for an adiabatic process.** Since direct homework questions without effort are not well received, I included my ideas to show my effort.

Comment: Direct homework questions without effort are not well received, but that doesn't mean showing effort keeps the question open. The post originally read like a "check my work" question, which is still off-topic. I do see that you have made an effort to focus on your conceptual question, which is what you should do. I will vote to reopen.

Comment: @BioPhysicist The last edit still failed to reopen the question, so I put in the meta link. I did not want to bring this up, but I've seen worse homework questions than this being extremely well received. There was one recent question of why a water molecule is bent, not straight - which a simple Google search would have given dozens of answers to. There was zero effort from OP, yet it has 30+ upvotes. As a new user, I'm beginning to feel that this is a pristine community whose fine workings are far beyond my scope and that it's my fault for littering the place with my obnoxious presence.

Comment: @TRC It's nothing personal. People see "my attempt" and think "check my work". Also your request of *"Also, I would appreciate an insight into why my first method was wrong as well."* also reads as "check my work". You have a conceptual question about the different between adiabatic work and stress-strain bulk compression. Honestly, it doesn't look like you need the exercise here. You could just start a new post focusing in on your conceptual question without including the exercise; it will probably be better recieved.

Comment: @TRC As for other questions that should be closed, keep in mind that questions are all viewed, closed, and reopened by different users. While ideally everyone is operating on the same standards, this is not actually the case. Sometimes questions are wrongfully closed, and also sometimes questions are wrongfully kept open. Because of this, a question being open/closed shouldn't have as much of an impact on another question being open or closed as one might originally think. Ultimately, if you do see a question you think should be closed, you should flag it to be closed.

Comment: Please see [this new question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/669077/why-does-an-elasticity-approach-for-an-adiabatically-compressed-bubble-give-a-di).

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thanks for that. That is a really great way to help the OP here.

Comment: Note that if this post is reopened then it should be closed again as a duplicate of the new question of @Chemomechanics. No sense in having the information split across two posts.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Many, many thanks for creating the new post, I'm grateful I finally got my query answered :)

Comment: @BioPhysicist I completely understand that it's natural for others' views to radically differ from mine as to which questions are suitable for this site. What put me off was that nobody bothered at first to point out *why* they felt that way - or guide me as to how I can improve the question. Those meta posts were of little help, as I'd already tried to emphasize in my last edit. As to the other questions I had mentioned, they were invariably HNQ's with 10+ upvotes so my flagging would be useless. I'm fine with the question being closed now, but I won't delete it as the new question links here