# What is the value of $p$ in Isothermal Bulk Modulus?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

So after differentiating the ideal gas equation and rearranging a bit, we get:
K=p
This was well and good until I started doing numerical problems and I realized I don't know whether to equate K to initial pressure or final pressure. This was made worse when some solutions equated it to initial pressure and others to final pressure.

I also find it important to mention that the difference between the two pressures is significant enough and they cannot be used interchangeably. (For example, in one case the value of K could be 100 kPa or 200kPa)

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the ideal gas stiffness is its *instantaneous* pressure at any point in time? (Assuming that the pressure is well defined under the circumstances.)

Comment: I have. But that still doesn't explain how I can apply this formula to questions with clear initial and final values. It's not like they state whether they want K initial or K final.

Comment: You simply don’t make the assumption of constant stiffness. Hard to say more without an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does an elasticity approach for an adiabatically compressed bubble give a different answer?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/669077/)

Comment: In other words, you can’t just use, say, Hooke’s Law when the stiffness varies; you have to integrate from a differential relation between stress and strain.

Comment: An example is this: the question gives the initial and final volume, explains that the conditions are isothermal and the also gives the initial pressure. Then it asks for final pressure and the bulk modulus.

Comment: From this description, it sounds like the question is seeking the final bulk modulus.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort to help. I've concluded the questions are just not framed well, hence they're using initial and final at random.